# Function app SDH Upgrade from 3.0.x to 4.0.x

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, azure-functions-core-tools

I am trying to upgrade function app sdk from 3.0.x to 4.0.x

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.13" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.0.1" />
```

I also have a reference to

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="4.2.1" />
```

However, after function app sdk upgrade the build is failing with below exception.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Mono.Cecil.AssemblyResolutionException: Failed to resolve assembly: 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Mono.Cecil.BaseAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name)
   at Mono.Cecil.DefaultAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference name)
   at Mono.Cecil.MetadataResolver.Resolve(TypeReference type)
   at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Resolve(TypeReference type)
   at Mono.Cecil.TypeReference.Resolve()
   at MakeFunctionJson.AttributeExtensions.IsWebJobsAttribute(CustomAttribute attribute) in /_/src/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator/AttributeExtensions.cs:line 52
   at MakeFunctionJson.ParameterInfoExtensions.<>c.<IsWebJobSdkTriggerParameter>b__0_0(CustomAttribute a) in /_/src/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator/ParameterInfoExtensions.cs:line 19
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at MakeFunctionJson.ParameterInfoExtensions.IsWebJobSdkTriggerParameter(ParameterDefinition parameterInfo) in /_/src/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator/ParameterInfoExtensions.cs:line 17
   at MakeFunctionJson.MethodInfoExtensions.<>c.<HasTriggerAttribute>b__4_0(ParameterDefinition p) in /_/src/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator/MethodInfoExtensions.cs:line 40
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at MakeFunctionJson.MethodInfoExtensions.HasTriggerAttribute(MethodDefinition method) in /_/src/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator/MethodInfoExtensions.cs:line 40
   at MakeFunctionJson.MethodInfoExtensions.HasValidWebJobSdkTriggerAttribute(MethodDefinition method) in /_/src/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator/MethodInfoExtensions.cs:line 24
   at MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.GenerateFunctions(IEnumerable`1 types)+MoveNext() in /_/src/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator/FunctionJsonConverter.cs:line 134
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.TryGenerateFunctionJsons() in /_/src/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator/FunctionJsonConverter.cs:line 194
   at MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.TryRun() in /_/src/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Generator/FunctionJsonConverter.cs:line 87
Error generating functions metadata
    SdBridge.FunctionHost   C:\Users\<<>>\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\4.0.1\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets 32
```

Please help with any pointers to resolve this issue -

Comment: Hello @Shiju Samuel, If the answer was helpful, Could you Please Accept it as an Answer, so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the workaround could be solve the above issue,

To upgrade Azure Function 3X to 4X we need to add this following in our `.csproj` file

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
```

And update your [**`Nuget package`**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions/) to `"Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.0.1"`

Make sure that you have installed [**Azure function core tool version 4x**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash%2Ckeda#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools) in your local .

Here is the workaround details that i have tried

[image]

For more information please refer this MS DOC: [Migrating from 3x to 4x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions?tabs=in-process%2Cv4&pivots=programming-language-csharp#migrating-from-3x-to-4x)